# Build in branch tests in IntelliJ like those in Sonar

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea

I'm using now the build-in plugin for Code Coverage in IntelliJ. But I need more detailed information about my unit tests. How can I get some branch test statistic in this IDE ?

Comment: To be honest the sonar tests are better for branch testing, if I understand correctly what you mean by that.

Comment: Yes, you do. I was wondering if there is some tool that I can integrate with IntelliJ (sth like sonar tests, but I would like to have acccess to the results in IntelliJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's nothing comparable to how sonar branch testing works in IntelliJ out of the box.

For example if a line of code has multiple execution paths, IntelliJ will mark it green if just one of the paths is executed.

In contrast, sonar will tell you that (for example) 1 of 3 possible paths were executed.

Your best bet is to run sonar locally or on a server and use sonar a plugin, for which I see 2 options that seem to be fairly up to date:

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7168?pr=idea

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7238?pr=idea

Good luck.